# How to find and count in MongoDB for specific items?

Tags: json, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-2.x

I would like to count the total number of each type of responses associated with each ID in the following JSON result that I am extracting from MongoDB:

```
{
  "test": [
    {
      "ID": 4, 
      "response": "A"
    }, 
    {
      "ID": 4, 
      "response": "B"
    }, 
    {
      "ID": 1, 
      "response": "A"
    }, 
    {
      "ID": 3, 
      "response": "B"
    }, 
    {
      "ID": 2, 
      "response": "C"
    }
  ]
}
// and so on...
```

So for example, I would like to structure the JSON into something like this:

```
{
    "test": [
        {
            "ID": 4,
            "A": 1,
            "B": 1
        },
        {
            "ID": 3,
            "B": 1
        },
        {
            "ID": 2,
            "C": 1
        },
        {
            "ID": 1,
            "A": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

My query looks something like this because I was just testing and trying to tally responses just for ID 4.

```
surveyCollection.find({"ID":4},{"ID":1,"response":1,"_id":0}).count():
```

But I get the following error: `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: It is generally  not a good idea to edit your post with given answer

Comment: Sorry about that. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is use the ["aggregation framework"](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/aggregation.html#aggregation-framework)

```
surveyCollection.aggregate([
    {"$unwind": "$test" }, 
    {"$group": {"_id": "$test.ID", "A": {"$sum": 1}, "B": {"$sum": 1}}},
    {"$group": {"_id": None, "test": {"$push": {"ID": "$ID", "A": "$A", "B": "$B"}}}}
])
```

From pymongo 3.x the [`aggregate()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate) method returns a  [`CommandCursor`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/command_cursor.html#pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor) over the result set so you may need to convert it  first into list.

```
In [16]: test
Out[16]: <pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor at 0x7fe999fcc630>

In [17]: list(test)
Out[17]: 
[{'_id': None,
  'test': [{'A': 1, 'B': 1},
   {'A': 1, 'B': 1},
   {'A': 1, 'B': 1},
   {'A': 2, 'B': 2}]}]
```

Use `return list(test)` instead